# Can the method set of a type defined in other package be modified?

Tags: logging, go

The built-in `log` and `log.Logger` don't provide `Error` or `Warning` methods like `Python`.

So I would like to write one for the built-in `Logger` type with the following code:

```
func (l *Logger) Error(v interface{}) {
    info := fmt.Sprintf("ERROR: %v", v)
    l.Println(info)
}
```

And I put the code above in a file `morelog.go` under `GOPATH/src/log`.

And in the `main.go` I wrote:

```
logger := log.New(os.Stdout, "Test", 1)
logger.Error("Error in main.")
```

When I run `go build`, I get:

```
./main.go:124: logger.Error undefined (type *log.Logger has no field or method Error)
```

I know I can achieve the similar goal by defining a new type and define methods on that type. But I think it could be better if I can ad the method directly to the buit-in type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rputikar is correct on the answer to your basic question.  You cannot define new methods on a type you didn't create.

One solution then, is to not get hung up on methods, just write a plain function.  Here is the method you wanted written as a function.

Edit2:  As Spirit Zhang correctly pointed out, my first version of this code lost the line number in the case of the Lshortfile or Llongfile flags.  This is an improvement:

```
func LogError(l *log.Logger, v interface{}) {
    l.Output(2, fmt.Sprint("ERROR: ", v))
}
```

Complete working example at playground:  http://play.golang.org/p/MJaKQLt24L

If you put this code in morelog.go, you can put morelog.go in the directory with your main program.  Or don't bother with a separate file for a couple of small functions; just put the LogError and LogWarning code right in the same file with your main program.

Edit: Example with default logger:  Edit2: **This Example does not work with Lshortfile or Llongfile.**  I'll leave it here so people can see the problem.  I don't know of an easy way to write these functions to use the default logger.

My example shows a LogError function that works for any logger.  If you just need to log errors for the default logger, it's even simpler:

```
func LogError(v interface{}) {
    log.Printf("ERROR: %v", v)
}
```

or even,

```
func LogError(v interface{}) {
    log.Print("ERROR:", v)
}
```

Comment: How can I print the line no of the actual position where I call LogError? If I use the standard Lshortfile flag, it will print the line no of the statement in LogError.

Comment: Try it.  This code does not affect the flags, it just adds the word warning or error.  (There are ways you can get the line number yourself, but you don't need those ways here.  The flags are still in effect.)

Comment: I tried, and the result is not good. It will print the line no in the LogError, not the place where I call LogError.

Comment: I'm very sorry to post quickly.  You're right of course.  And frustratingly, there's the nice Output method, but there is no way to call it on the default logger.  I'll update my solutions above.

Answer (score 5):

Both of these answers are correct so I'll throw in a few more alternatives. You can't define methods on a type you didn't define. Functions are indeed one way you can do this but you can also do this by redefining the type or wrapping the type.

For instance if you don't care about splitting the outfile and just want to modify the log line then you can do one of these.

Redefine the type:

```
type MyLogger log.Logger

func (l MyLogger) Info(msg string, args ...interface{}) {
    log.Logger(l).Printf(msg, args...)
}

func (l MyLogger) Error(msg string, args ...interface{} {
    log.Logger(l).Printf("ERROR: " + msg, args...)
}
```

Or Wrap the type:

```
type MyLogger struct {
  log.Logger
}

func (l MyLogger) Info(msg string, args ...interface{}) {
  l.Printf(msg, args...)
}

func (l MyLogger) Error(msg string, args ...interface{}) {
  l.Printf("ERROR: " + msg, args...)
}
```

Redefining the type will limit the method set you can call on it to the ones you define. You won't be able to reuse the *Printf methods without casting it first. Wrapping the type by embedding it will allow you to call the *Printf methods and wrap those methods with your own.  You can see examples of this in the implementations of the Info and Error methods for each case.

Answer (score 2):

You can not override the method on a type you didn't create. Similarly you can not define new methods on a type you didn't create.

For your needs you can simply have two instances of log.Logger one for warning and one for error.

http://play.golang.org/p/DQjIvk-wfI

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "os"
)

func main() {

    errorLogger := log.New(os.Stderr, "ERROR: ", log.LstdFlags)
    warnLogger := log.New(os.Stdout, "WARNING: ", log.LstdFlags)

    errorLogger.Println("Hello, playground")
    warnLogger.Println("Hello, playground")
}
```

Comment: Can I use both logger to one log file?

Comment: You can, but you lose goroutine serialization.  A logger uses a mutex to ensure that writes from multiple goroutines are kept atomic.  Once there are two loggers on the same file, you risk garbled output if goroutines attempt to write through the separate loggers simultaneously.

Comment: @Sonia Does that mean I cannot use one single log file for different modules of my application? Just like what I can do in Python.

Comment: Different parts of your program can all use the default logger safely, but if you want to use a custom logger (to customize error and warning messages for example) then you need to pass that *log.Logger to each part of your program.  If they all use the same logger, then you are safe.